# Booting a SuperMicro from virtual iSCSI CD-ROM

Tags: boot, iscsi

I correctly set up the iSCSI server with SCST, I can login to the target via iscsiadm and mount the iSCSI resource, a CDROM based on ISO image exposed as LUN 0.
When I try to boot a SuperMicro X10DRi-LN4+ the motherboard asks the iSCSI server for the capabilities of LUN 0, it gets the reply from it and then the mother board sends a close command.

On the POST I get this message:

```
iSCSI Target Name: <correct name>
iSCSI Target IP address: <correct IP address>

LUN ID: 0    <<<<< the right one
...

Attempting to connect to target disk using MAC address (AC1F6B....)
ERROR: Failed to find specified LUN! Please check your iSCSI configuration
```

By using iscsiadm I can see that the iSCSI server exposes the correct LUN 0 and in that case the Linux client sees it as a CD-ROM and I can even mount it.

So I think I have correctly configured the iSCSI server and rather the problem resides on the SuperMicro BIOS settings.

Do I have to tell the motherboard that behind the LUN  there is a CD-ROM?
Is the statement "Attempting to target **disk** using ..." meaningful? I.e. is the motherboard looking for a block device and when it sees that behind the LUN 0 ythere is a CD-ROM it gives up?I would appreciate a confirmation on this because I am a beginner as to iSCSI.

I haven't found in other discussion and on the Internet any statement that said that the client must be instructed on what type of media is behind a LUN so I assume it doesn't matter.

Comment: Still the same issue :-)
I contacted the SCST Mailing list and the SuperMicro support server, no way to get it work.

Anybody who could give even a small clue on how to proceed? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I updated the BIOS to the latest release (3.2) and set to the default all the settings and configured the settings from scratch.

By choosing among the boot options the "UEFI shell" I could see that the unit was visible and in the UEFI shell I could navigate in its filesystem. "map" should be a standard EFI command.

The boot option that did the trick was **UEFI Hard disk: UEFI < x >**

SuperMicro recognizes the bootloader on the LUN and depending on the OS the < x > it's replaced by **Windows Boot Manager** or **OS**, of course you need to cycle the server at least once for the server to be able to use such information.